# Can't understand how to style Android app for pre-Lollipop devices using Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, android-theme

My brain is about to blow on Android's **themes** and **styles**. Somebody, help me, please!
I'm trying to create a **theme** for my app to provide as similar look for **pre- and post-Lollipop** devices as possible. So, I've inherited my theme from `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` and my activities from `AppCompatActivity` ans set up `colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark` and `colorAccent`. All that went well. The problems started when I tried to style background and text color. I've set `android:textColorPrimary` and `android:textColorSecondary` and got what I wanted on Lollipop device, but not on KitKat, so I've added `textColorPrimary` and `textColorSecondary` attributes to theme and after that **Android Studio** said that it can't build the app because these attributes can't be found. Same happened when I've tried to add `colorBackground`. I've tried to google it but wasn't able to found something useful about what attributes are provided by which theme and what should I use in my situation.

Answer (score 2):

You must have to create two values folder one for lollipop **values-v21** and simple **values** for pre-lollipop

See this style for pre-lollipop devices just paste it to **values/styles.xml**

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

    </style>


    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.TransparentActivity">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

see [official documentation on android blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style the app for different apis, you have to make a folder name values-v(sdk version) for e.g values-v21 for lollipop, values-v19 for kitkat,... but in this case I think you only need to create values-v21.

inside that folder, create an xml file style.xml and based on the api to use the appropriate attributes.